# Error Loading Module ./exp.so Undefined Symbol

Tags: python, swig

I'm trying to wrap a c code to be callable from python.

code:

```c
#include "stdio.h"
#include "stdlib.h"
#include "time.h"
#include "math.h"
int givernd(int krp1,int krp2)
{
    int trye;
    int inp1=krp1;
    int inp2=krp2;
    time_t broke;
    if(inp1 > inp2)
    {   printf("error");
        exit(0);
    }
    if((inp1)=(inp2-1))
    {   printf("error");
        exit(0);
    }
    srand(time(&broke));
    trye=rand()%krp2;
    if(trye<krp1)
    {   
        return(trye+krp1+1);
    }
    if(trye==krp1)
    {
        return(trye+1);
    }
    return(trye);
}
```

.i file:

```c
/* now1.i */
%module now1
%{
/* Put header files here or function declarations like below */

 extern int givernd(int krp1,int krp2);
%}

extern int givernd(int krp1,int krp2);
```

trial 1:

```py
$ swig -python now1.i
$ gcc -c -fPIC now1_wrap.c -I/usr/include/python2.7 
$ gcc -shared -fpic now1_wrap.o -o now1_wrap.so -lc
$ python
Python 2.7.3 (default, Jun 22 2015, 19:43:34) 
[GCC 4.6.3] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import now1
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: dynamic module does not define init function (initnow1)
```

trial 2:

```py
$ swig -python now1.i
$ gcc -fpic -I/usr/include/python2.7 -c now1_wrap.c
$ gcc -shared now1_wrap.o -o now1.so
$ python
Python 2.7.3 (default, Jun 22 2015, 19:43:34) 
[GCC 4.6.3] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more      information.
>>> import now1
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: ./now1.so: undefined symbol: givernd
>>>
```

What am I doing wrong?

I'm wondering if I need to add a test function that will be the starting point duplicating main, but the swig manual says it's not required.

Answer (score 2):

You haven't said what the first file, the one which contains your definition of `givernd` is called, but assuming it's called givernd.c you'll need to compile and link that as well as the wrapper that SWIG generated, e.g.:

```
$ swig -python now1.i
$ gcc -c -fPIC now1_wrap.c -I/usr/include/python2.7 -o now1_wrap.o
$ gcc -c -fPIC givernd.c -I/usr/include/python2.7 -o givernd.o
$ gcc -shared -fpic now1_wrap.o givernd.o -o now1_wrap.so -lc
```

(Note: your call to gcc was also missing -o)

Comment: thanks.the tutorial was pretty poor and i foolishly didnt add  " -o " either.again thanks a lot.